Start recurring alarm on Android phone from Android watch
I am trying to develop a watch app that the user can initiate from an Android watch and the alarm will annunicate on a paired phone, with the phone locked.  It appears the only technique for a watch to contact a phone without user setup is to use a notification and use of a notification comes with the restriction that the repetition period and sound for an alarm is fixed in configuration for all notifications.  Can this be changed?  Can the reminder period start at 10 seconds and then escalate to a larger value specified by an algorithm?
I tried using passing messages by using MessageClient
